# How to Customize Outlook mail for getting status

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Every week I have to send a mail with excel attachment to my team members to get their status on task. After getting the reply from those people, I have to merge all data together and send it to my boss.

I am thinking of creating a custom form or an Infopath mail with vb script to send the data as comma separate values to me,Then I will create an add-in for outlook at my end to read through those specific subject mails and create the final document.

Is this possible? Any idea on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. 
I would advise you to look up http://dev.office.com for tips on how to achieve most of this plus all the other stuff you can do :)

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the reply. Can we share a custom form with others without installing any add-in? any sample link will be helpful :)

Comment: Well, you basically make your form available in the form of an add-in. That's how it works :)